# How can I stop sliding after scrolling when I hold or press a button? [REACT-NATIVE]

Tags: react-native, scrollview, react-native-reanimated

How can I stop sliding after scrolling when I hold or press a button?
Click [here](https://ibb.co/TYB9wWh) to watch example. Any ideas?

Comment: Even looking at the gif i don't get what you want to achieve, what do you mean with stopping the scroll action with a button?

Comment: When I scroll the list and release it, it starts to slide. When I hold or press a button, the slide stops immediately